# Store images in a folder for FlexSlider extension in TYPO3 6

Tags: php, typo3, flexslider

This question might be very basic, I'm an amateur in TYPO3.

I needed an image slider for my website and found this extension `FlexSlider`. I want this extensions to take all the image records from a folder, instead of manually creating a record for each image.

This is what I did so far

I have my set of images in `fileadmin/templates/images` folder.
I then created `File Collection` under `System Records` and stored the `fileadmin/templates/images` into this.

I created a Backend Layout for a page `slider page` and inserted the `flexSlider` extension to it.

In `flexSlider/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt` is added this:

```
persistence.storagePid = 81
```

`81` being the pageId of the `File Collection Record Folder` .

Of course, this is not the final step to this process. Do I need to write a PHP Code or something to insert the images from fileadmin folder to the System record folder? I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. The named flexslider extension has its own db table and expects records in there to be rendered. The `storagePid` option is just the place where those records are stored, if not on the page where the extension is inserted on.

A record consists of more than just an image. You can specify an alt-text, title and subtitle of the slide and so on. Assuming that your slides won't change every 5 minutes, it is worth the (little) additional effort of creating those records in comparison to find another extension/solution for your plan.

The extension has (for instance) also the advantage of being responsive out of the box, which you may take into account for decision as well. I use it quite often and really like it.

Comment: As far as I understand, I can do something like this: I write some code which will insert data into the `flexSlider table` from my `fileadmin folder`. In this way I need not create 100 flexrecords for 100 images.

Comment: Of course, you can (Have you tried something?). But that makes no sense for me at this point. Do you want to have one page with 100 slides on it, which would take a loooooong time to load?

Comment: Yes, I did write something like that, but for a different purpose. And yes, makes sense, did not think about the transition time. Thank You for the answer :)